# How to modify DigitalOcean DOKS Cluster-Autoscaler parameters?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, amazon-eks, autoscaling

The task is to configure Cluster Autoscaler(CA) with 1 minute of scale-down time in DigitalOcean DOKS.

DOKS by default supports CA and having 10 mins of scale down time. Now i need to add below parameters as per my requirement.

```
Parameters need to modify to:
 --scale-down-unneeded-time=10s
 --scale-down-delay-after-add=30s
```

I tried in DO, but there is no place for adding/changing the parameters(or not sure if im missing anything).

Then tried in AWS EKS Cluste,  [Configured CA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html)(no default support) with the above parameters, working fine.

Could anyone help me to configure these parameters in DOKS?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root after the entier day.

It may be good for someone, so adding.

DigitalOcean K8S Cluster supports Cluster-AutoScaler(CA) by default. But not giviing explicit option to change its configurations.
We cannot change CA behaviour by passing parameters.

There is work in progress:
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/3556

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/3556#issuecomment-877015122